# Mathematical therefore symbol (∴) needed for documenting circuit analysis calculations

Tags: circuit-analysis, analysis, math-notation

When doing circuit analysis calculations I use the mathematical therefore symbol in my calculations and need to document my iterations to support my analysis. There is no ASCII code for the "therefore" symbol. There is a UNICODE U+2211 for it that doesn't work. I had to cut and paste the one in the title. Any pointers here?

Comment: Do you want this: ∴? The internet seems to think this should be U+2234, not U+2211. (But I'm not getting the correct symbol using Alt+2234)

Comment: Try Unicode U+2234

Comment: This would be a stack overflow question.  On this group you would type in `\$\Rightarrow\$` to get \$\Rightarrow\$.

Comment: Definitely the wrong stack. https://fsymbols.com/keyboard/windows/alt-codes/laptop/

Comment: I'm not using a laptop and I have done my due diligence searching the net for a solution with no answer that works.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it pertains to the use of word processors.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has nothing to do with electrical engineering.

Comment: Unicode U+2234 gives me ║

Comment: It has a lot to do with circuit analysis calculations!

Comment: ALT+8756 gives 4 not therefore already tried that also...

Comment: You may be out of luck. [Code Page 437](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437)

Comment: Just use the HTML entity `&there4;`, which renders as ∴

Comment: Just use the HTML entity &there4;, which renders as ∴   Except that I am documenting my analysis in a plain text file.

Answer (score 1):

Did you google it?

> Because the symbol is not usually available on keyboards and within fonts, and to prevent compatibility issues, users have substituted a colon followed by a period (":.") to represent it.

Source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Therefore_sign

Comment: Yes but I did not find that one...  Interesting, thanks!  I actually looked at that and missed it.

Comment: Because I skipped over the freemasonry part as being of no interest.  Strange they would put that there...

Answer (score 1):

On my iPad here with a BT keyboard.

> ™ alt-T.
>
> Block quote. Alt-Q
>   ∑ Alt W
>
> ---
>
> FWIW

Mathjax

Basically use HTML for best or Mathjax which is “bound by \$ before and after `\therefore`

I am an EE, \$\therefore\$ I think outside    the Ω box.

Comment: But no, therefore...   Seems like I need to use :. but don't think others with a mathematical background will recognize it.

Comment: Basically use HTML for best or Mathjax I think \$\therefore\$, I am \therefore